# How to format space in panda output?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I am using pandas to format some data

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{0:,.0f}'.format
print pd.DataFrame(years, columns=['A', "B", "C", 'D', "E", "Total"])
```

and ended up with some unfortunate spacing

```
19   57    54   28   1,078,925       1,294,710  2,373,636
20   58    55   29   1,165,239       1,398,287  2,563,526
```

How can I even things out?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this result.  Can you provide sample code that generates both `years` and the output you're seeing?  Also, you have seven columns in your output but only six columns.  Is one of these columns an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
years.columns = years.columns.str.replace('\s+', '')
```